# Use meaningful words to get tuple elements

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, tuples

For example, I have a tuple like

```
std::tuple<T0, T1, T2> tp;
```

I can get its element by `std::get()` function like

```
auto e0 = std::get<0>(tp);
```

I prefer to using meaningful index to access the element other than the number. A way to do it is to define an enum like

```
enum MyEnum
{
    WHAT_T0_MEANS = 0,
    WHAT_T1_MEANS = 1,
    WHAT_T2_MEANS = 2
};
```

Thus I can use a friendly version of get like

```
auto e0 = std::get<WHAT_T0_MEANS>(tp);
```

The problem is that sometimes I find the order of types in the tuple is not friendly and change it to like `std::tuple<T1, T0, T2>`. But it is so easy to forget to change the order of elements in the enum. A good way may be to define what T0 means in the class T0 or use map to find what T0 means, or else. And then write some function to get the elements through what T0 means. Any way to do it? Here the what T0 means are not necessary to by enum elements. It can be a type or anything else.

If T0, T1, and T2 are different types. A function like

```
T MyGet<T>(tp)
```

where T can be T0, T1 or T2, is okay.

Comment: Alternatively, why not use a struct or a class if you want to define meaningful names for your data?

Comment: So many similar structures. Using tuple template makes my work easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is discussion underway:

- [n3584](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3584.html) Wording for accessing Tuplefields by type
- on the isocpp forums https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/std-proposals/N-kIXNrkTUk

Right now, you can use tagged elements with something like Fusion Map:

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/map.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/at_key.hpp>
using namespace boost::fusion;

typedef map<
   pair<struct what_t1_means, int>
 , pair<struct what_t2_means, int> >
map_type;

int main()
{
    map_type m { 42, -42 };

    auto i1 = at_key<what_t1_means>(m);
    auto i2 = at_key<what_t2_means>(m);
}
```

I opted to use `int` twice, to highlight that the 'key types' are separate from the 'tuple' types.

See it live on **http://liveworkspace.org/code/4CxV4T$0**

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>
using std::size_t;
/*
```

Build a single `type_list`.  Then build the `tuple` from said `type_list`, and index getting similarly.

Basic metaprogramming boilerplate:

```
*/    
template<typename... Ts>
struct type_list {};
template<typename T, typename list, typename=void>
struct index_of;
template<typename T, typename T0, typename...Ts>
struct index_of<T, type_list<T0, Ts...>, typename std::enable_if<
  std::is_same<T, T0>::value
>::type>: std::integral_constant< size_t, 0 >{};
template<typename T, typename T0, typename...Ts>
struct index_of<T, type_list<T0, Ts...>, typename std::enable_if<
  !std::is_same<T, T0>::value
>::type>: std::integral_constant< size_t, index_of<T, type_list<Ts...>>::value+1 >{};

template<template<typename...>class target, typename source>
struct copy_types;
template<template<typename...>class target, template<typename...>class src, typename... Ts>
struct copy_types<target, src<Ts...>> {
  typedef target<Ts...> type;
};
template<template<typename...>class target, typename source>
using CopyTypes = typename copy_types<target, source>::type;
/*
```

Now we create one list of types, and use it to define our tuple, and a `get` function:

```
*/
typedef type_list<int, double, char> my_types;
typedef CopyTypes< std::tuple, my_types > my_tuple;
template<typename T>
T& get_type( my_tuple& t ) {
  return std::get< index_of<T, my_types>::value >(t);
}
template<typename T>
T const& get_type( my_tuple const& t ) {
  return std::get< index_of<T, my_types>::value >(t);
}
/*
```

If we want tagged types, we can use `boost::mpl`, or roll something quick like this:

```
*/
template<typename Tag, typename T>
struct tagged_type {
  typedef Tag tag;
  typedef T type;
};

template< typename tagged_type >
using GetType = typename tagged_type::type;
template< typename tagged_type >
using GetTag = typename tagged_type::tag;

template< template<typename...> class target, typename tagged_list >
struct copy_tagged_types;

template< template<typename...> class target, typename... tagged_Ts >
struct copy_tagged_types< target, type_list<tagged_Ts...> >:
  copy_types< target, type_list< GetType<tagged_Ts>... > >
{};

template< template<typename...> class target, typename tagged_list >
using CopyTaggedTypes = typename copy_tagged_types< target, tagged_list >::type;

template< typename Tag, typename tagged_list >
struct get_tag_index;

template< typename Tag, typename...Tagged_Ts >
struct get_tag_index< Tag, type_list< Tagged_Ts...> >:
  index_of< Tag, type_list< GetTag<Tagged_Ts>... > > {};
/*
```

and now we have the basics of a tagged template metaprogramming library.

Use would be something like:

```
*/
typedef type_list<
  tagged_type<struct bob, int>,
  tagged_type<struct alice, int>
> my_tagged_types;

typedef CopyTaggedTypes< std::tuple, my_tagged_types > my_tuple2;

template<typename Tag>
auto get_tag( my_tuple2& tup )
  ->decltype(std::get< get_tag_index< Tag, my_tagged_types >::value >( tup ))
{
  return std::get< get_tag_index< Tag, my_tagged_types >::value >( tup );
}
template<typename Tag>
auto get_tag( my_tuple2 const& tup )
  ->decltype(std::get< get_tag_index< Tag, my_tagged_types >::value >( tup ))
{
  return std::get< get_tag_index< Tag, my_tagged_types >::value >( tup );
}
/*
```

which is basically a case of "roll your own `boost::mpl`".  :)  Live example [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1p9wHk%2415)

```
*/
int main() {
   my_tuple t1;
   get_type<char>(t1) = 'a'; 
   my_tuple2 t2;
   get_tag<bob>(t2) = 7;
}
```

Comment: Weehoo. That was a whole flock of yaks requesting a shave! +1 for the effort